# Backups initiated to pull from remote Ubuntu hosts

Tags: server, backup, gui

I am looking for a user-friendly solution to back-up a small cluster of Ubuntu servers.  Ideally, I'd like to take a minimal representation of the standard configuration (i.e. a list of installed Ubuntu packages) then a copy of all edited configuration and user files.  While 'unusual' (I suspect) I'd like to do this by running the backup software on a host (Windows or Ubuntu) with a lot of local disk available - and use it to back-up remote servers - ideally without requiring any special services to be installed on the systems that require backups.

I'm struggling to find a backup tool that works this way (i.e. with a UI on the host with the backup drives locally attached - looking to back-up data from remote servers over SSH/rsync.

I realise that I could write some scripts to do this - but I'm really looking for a GUI that will make it easy for me to manage ongoing incremental backups and to restore anything from an entire system to an individual file in the case of a failure.

Are there any Ubuntu-supported backup tools that work this way (i.e pulling data from a remote live system to the system storing the backups - versus pushing data from an operational system to remote storage)?

Comment: I *suspect* that a cron job might be the best option, but you could just use a tool like [webmin](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=webmin&t=canonical&ia=web) to write to a share?

Comment: Sorry, context was missing; [webmin backup documentation](https://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/Filesystem_Backup) to help perform backups. Can use in conjunction with `rsync`. Useful alternative could be much like Nethserver uses - but [these are good options](https://www.how2shout.com/tools/ubuntu-server-web-gui.html) as well.

Comment: As far as I can tell, I'd need to install webmin on every host in my ubuntu cluster - whereas I want to install something once on a separate host (with lots of disk) and have it manage the backups of several remote systems - over ssh or rsync, or something like that.  I also found the article about the other options - but, as far as I can tell, they all want to be installed on the system to be backed up (pushing to remote media) rather than pulling data from a remote operational host.

Comment: Correct - hence the comment and not the answer. Just thought I'd throw these options out there should you not achieve what you're after. I'm sure there is some clustering solution out there (I *thought* Nethserver did this) that gives you a command-and-control option for backups!

Comment: What is the data you want to backup ? It is very important to consider if there is any database running for example. In some cases you may require a maintenance window to proceed.
Also what is the daily volume ? And the network speed available ?

Comment: The data: sundry files and config.  Sure, databases are running - but I'd be happy to only back up their regular dump files.  I don't need/want to take down the servers... The total data volume is small (relative to 1GBps ethernet) and the daily delta should be trivial.

Answer (score 0):

I guess BackupPC would be a tool to consider.

It is an Enterprise-grade Open Source Project.

I used it myself way back. Setting it up correctly can be a drag (well it was back in the days), but once it is setup it is very stable and smooth. It has data pooling to reduce the amount of traffic and disc space. So let's say you have 20 ubuntu 18.04 servers. You don't backup the OS 20 times, If it is the same file BackupPc keeps one of them and marks them in a pool for all 20 servers. Very clever!

It can also backup other OS, like Windows and MacOS.

https://backuppc.github.io/backuppc/

From the page:

"BackupPC is a high-performance, enterprise-grade system for backing up Linux, Windows and macOS PCs and laptops to a server's disk. BackupPC is highly configurable and easy to install and maintain."

But you def. can use it for servers, too. There is no difference.

Comment: Oh I just saw this.... No client-side software is needed. Haven't used it in a while. So you might not need a client at all, interesting.

Comment: I've taken a brief look at BackupPC - but, to me, it looks as if it also works by having the backup software installed on the hosts being backed up - rather than on the host on which the backup media is mounted.  Am I missing something?

Comment: The old version yes, but the new one states "No client-side software is needed. On WinXX the standard smb protocol is used to extract backup data. On linux, unix or MacOSX clients, rsync, tar (over ssh/rsh/nfs) or ftp is used to extract backup data. Alternatively, rsync can also be used on WinXX (using cygwin), since rsync provides for efficient transfers and allows incremental backups to detect almost all changes."